# Is it possible to run nodes without source?

Tags: c++, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working with ROS Kinetic in docker. I'm doing several thing through jenkins and several scripts to put my project (wrapped with ros) and all the dependency in the docker.
As I want to keep my docker as light as possible I would like to remove all the source code from the package. The ros project is orbslam (https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) with some update to publish the transform and some other data.

All the ros part is working well in the docker. But is there a way to "ros run" my RGBD app without having source code in the docker ? rosbuild isn't creating any exe that I could run without source ? Maybe only with lib .so ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269046/is-it-possible-to-run-nodes-without-source-?/) by [Bastienm](https://answers.ros.org/users/31434/bastienm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-17**:
You may be able to just copy over the [`build` space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Build_Space) of your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do this routinely to build on one machine (my laptop) and deploy to a target machine (the robot).

First, make sure all of the packages you're building have install directives set up in your `CMakeLists.txt` For more information, refer to the [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html).

The rest of these instructions assume you use `catkin-tools` to build your workspace. You can do all of this with `catkin_make`, but I don't use it, so I can't give you instructions.

1. Choose a directory to deploy your code to. It needs to exist on both your build machine (or build container) and your target machine. If it's in your home directory, the user names have to be the same in both environments. I usually create a directory in `/opt` and use  `sudo chown` to give it to my user.
2. On the build machine, set up your catkin workspace for install builds:

   `catkin config --install`

   `catkin config --install-space /opt/my_workspace`
3. Build your workspace with `catkin build`. Catkin will do the normal build, but it will also install everything to the install space. All your libraries will be in `/opt/my_workspace/lib/`, all your executables from each package will be in `/opt/my_workspace/lib/<pkg_name>/` and all of the files you install to the share directory, like launch files, will be in `/opt/my_workspace/share/<pkg_name>/`. If you've ever poked around in `/opt/ros/`, you'll notice that this is exactly how the binary packages you install with `apt-get` are laid out.
4. Copy your install space from build machine to target machine. You can do this with `scp` or `rsync` for physical machines. Since you're using Docker, you can probably build this step into your Dockerfile.

The one downside to this is that the install space isn't totally portable--you have to deploy the files to the same path as you installed them to when you built them. There are ways around that (that's how the ROS build server works), but it's probably not worth the trouble. If you need that kind of power, you should just spin up a ROS build farm and make Debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastienm](https://answers.ros.org/users/31434/bastienm/) on 2017-08-18**:
Thanks for your answer ! I'll check how to do it with catkin_make, other way I'll use catkin-tools.

**Comment by [Zekarias Taye Hirpo](https://answers.ros.org/users/82070/zekarias-taye-hirpo/) on 2021-08-23**:
Did you able to solve it using catkin-tools ?